# In a Manipulate[], control timing of Autorun

Tags: dynamic, manipulate, animation

I've made a gauge like instrument that will get used to prompt someone to maintain rhythmic breathing patterns during heart/brain coherence training.

```
Manipulate[ListLinePlot[(Table[#, {10}] & /@ Range[10]) a,
  PlotRange -> {{0, 11}, {0, 10}},
  AspectRatio -> 3.5,
  ImageSize -> 100,
  PlotStyle -> LightGray,
  Axes -> {False, True},
  Filling -> Axis,
  FillingStyle -> LightGreen,
  Frame -> True,
  FrameTicks -> {{True, True}, {None, None}}
  ], {a, 0, 1},
 Paneled -> False,
 ControlType -> None,
 AutorunSequencing -> 3
 ]
```

Note that after executing the code you'll need to click on the `+` in the upper right corner of the output to get to `Autorun`, which will get you the following:

[image]

This nicely runs up and down, but now I'd like the ability to set four things programatically.

- A default speed at which the gauge will run up (e.g., 5 seconds);
- A default speed at which the gauge will run down (e.g., 4 seconds);
- A timed delay at the bottom (e.g., 2 seconds, which I currently kind of
  hack with `AutorunSequencing -> 3`); and
- A timed delay at the top.

I had originally tried doing this with `Animate[]`, but it seemed to have too many limitations.

Maybe the same holds for `Manipulate[]` and I have to go to basics with `Dynamic[]`.

I thought it worth asking.
Any suggestions welcomed.

Comment: There are informations about this in "manipulate secret revealed", *version 2007* (http://library.wolfram.com/infocenter/Conferences/7001/), page 12. There is something better elsewhere, but I can't find it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sorry, I missed the pause at the top.  Corrected:

```
breather[up_, p1_, down_, p2_] := 
 With[{f = Interpolation[{Accumulate@{0, up, p1, down, p2}, {0, 1, 1, 0, 0}}\[Transpose], 
     InterpolationOrder -> 1]}, 
  Animate[ListLinePlot[(Table[#, {10}] & /@ Range[10]) f[a], 
    PlotRange -> {{0, 11}, {0, 10}}, AspectRatio -> 3.5, ImageSize -> 100, 
    PlotStyle -> LightGray, Axes -> {False, True}, Filling -> Axis, 
    FillingStyle -> LightGreen, Frame -> True, 
    FrameTicks -> {{True, True}, {None, None}}], {a, 0, up + p1 + down + p2}, 
   AnimationRate -> 1]
]
```

Usage is simply times in seconds for up, pause1, down, and pause2:

```
breather[3, 0.7, 2, 2]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: You got this one by a nose;-)  With two solutions, both relying on Animate, your use of With seems just a tiny bit more elegant and direct.  Many thanks.

Comment: @Jagra Thank you. I like the fact that this method is easily extendable.  You could change it to accept two vectors, one a list of times and the other a list of the positions.  You could also experiment with different interpolation orders or methods, which might be more lifelike.

Comment: +1; I agree that this is a nicer solution.  Good reminder of the usefulness/adaptability of `InterpolatingFunction` objects.

Answer (score 3):

We can do this using `Animate[]` by manually constructing the list of values that `a` takes, and setting `AnimationRate` to give the correct times, in seconds:

```
rhythmicBreath[tUp_, tDown_, tTop_, tBottom_] := 
 Animate[ListLinePlot[(Table[#, {10}] & /@ Range[10]) a, 
   PlotRange -> {{0, 11}, {0, 10}}, AspectRatio -> 3.5, 
   ImageSize -> 100, PlotStyle -> LightGray, Axes -> {False, True}, 
   Filling -> Axis, FillingStyle -> LightGreen, Frame -> True, 
   FrameTicks -> {{True, True}, {None, None}}], 
   {a, Join @@ {Range[0, 1, .05/tUp], ConstantArray[1, 20 tTop // Round], 
     Reverse@Range[0, 1, .05/tDown], ConstantArray[0, 20 tBottom // Round]}},
   Paneled -> False, AnimationRate -> 20]
```

`rhythmicBreath[5, 4, 2, 2]` produces an autorunning graphic with a visible control:
[image: Mathematica graphics]

In version 8, the animation slider pauses during the "holds" (repeated ones or zeros in the list of `a` values).  There are obvious hacky ways around this, but maybe someone has a nice solution.

Comment: Thanks for an interesting solution +1 from me.